# How can I prove that $a^{2} < b^{2} $implies that $a < b$ in the Real Numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

The answer to my question doesn't seem to exist elsewhere on the internet.

I have the sets $ A=\{ a : a\in R: a > 0,\ a^2 < 3\} $ and $ B=\{ b: b\in R: b>0,\ b^2 > 3\} $, and I'm just trying to formally show that $ \forall a \in A$, and $\forall b \in B$, $a\ \lt\ b$.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to prove is false. Consider a positive element of $A$ and a negative element of $B$.

Comment: What about $a=2$ and $b=-3$?

Comment: Haha.  lurl.  Sorry, guys.

Comment: I edited it, so now it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: "$\{a : a \in \mathbb R:\ldots\}$" is rather prolix. Just say "$\{a \in \mathbb R :\ldots\}$".

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{ a\in R: a > 0,\ a^2 < 3\}$ and $B=\{ b\in R: b > 0,\ b^2 > 3\}$.

Since for all $ a\in A $ , $ b\in B $ : $ -a^2 > -3 $ and $ b^2 > 3 $.

$ b^2 - a^2 > 0 $
Then, $ (b-a)(b+a) > 0 $
We know that a+b>0, then clearly $ b - a > 0 $

As a conclusion, we have $ b > a $.

Sauf erreur.